# Positioning sprites in 2d games

Tags: 2d, sprite

I'm developing a 2d game without any APIs or libraries. Yeah, I know I'm reinventing the wheel and everything, but I chose this way as an opportunity to learn several aspects of programming at once (like input handling, audio playing, etc)

Currently I'm stuck with a problem related to sprite drawing. First I'd like to know witch way is better to store sprites for drawing, assuming I have the sprites I need all in one sprite sheet:

1 - store just the coordinates for each sprite for each entity, and then draw only the corresponding part of the sprite sheet when the entity should draw itself, or

2 - store actual parts of the sprite sheet in each entity and the draw each the cropped sprite;

Another thing I'd like to learn is how to handle sprites with different sizes. See Zelda, for example. Link's walking sprites are all about the same size, let's say 18 x 22 px, regardless of his position or orientation. But when he attacks, the sprites include his sword and depending on his orientation, some sprites are wider and some others are longer.

What I want to know is if there's a good way of positioning and aligning sprites with different sizes relative to my character's foot, for example. Should I store some sort of offset for each sprite along with the sprites?

Comment: Options 1 and 2 sound like the same thing.  Can you clarify them?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy In both options I have a sprite sheet with all the sprites. In option 1, on the game creation, I store the coordinates for sprites needed in the sprite sheet and when the function to update my canvas is called, I use the coordinates to get a subImage from the sprite sheet then draw this subImage as a sprite. In option 2, I get all the subImages before the and store them in an array rather than just the coordinates so when the function to draw is called, I already have the sprite to draw.